# Change specific value in column with conditions in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a daframe such as :

```
COL1       COL2 
C.lupus    10
C.lupus    20
C.famil    90
O.cuniculus 30
O.cuniculus 70 
O.cuniculus 10
```

and I would like tu replace each `COL1 ==` to `O.cuniculus` and where `COL2 < 50` by `O.spatacus`

Here I should then get :

```
  COL1       COL2 
    C.lupus    10
    C.lupus    20
    C.famil    90
    O.spatacus 30
    O.cuniculus 70 
    O.spatacus 10
```

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A base R option using `replace`

```
transform(
  df,
  COL1 = replace(COL1, COL1 == "O.cuniculus" & COL2 < 50, "O.spatacus")
)
```

gives

```
         COL1 COL2
1     C.lupus   10
2     C.lupus   20
3     C.famil   90
4  O.spatacus   30
5 O.cuniculus   70
6  O.spatacus   10
```

---

A `data.table` option works in a similar manner

```
setDT(df)[COL1 == "O.cuniculus" & COL2 < 50, COL1 := "O.spatacus"]
```

such that

```
          COL1 COL2
1:     C.lupus   10
2:     C.lupus   20
3:     C.famil   90
4:  O.spatacus   30
5: O.cuniculus   70
6:  O.spatacus   10
```

Answer (score 1):

You could subset your data.frame and then assign the new values with `<-`.

If your data frame were called `data`:

```
data
#         COL1 COL2
#1     C.lupus   10
#2     C.lupus   20
#3     C.famil   90
#4 O.cuniculus   30
#5 O.cuniculus   70
#6 O.cuniculus   10
```

You could subset to only those rows that fulfill the conditions:

```
data[data$COL2 < 50 & data$COL1 == "O.cuniculus",]
#         COL1 COL2
#4 O.cuniculus   30
#6 O.cuniculus   10
```

Then subset also only `COL1`:

```
data[data$COL2 < 50 & data$COL1 == "O.cuniculus","COL1"]
#[1] "O.cuniculus" "O.cuniculus"
```

And then assign the new value:

```
data[data$COL2 < 50 & data$COL1 == "O.cuniculus","COL1"] <- "O.spatacus"
data
#         COL1 COL2
#1     C.lupus   10
#2     C.lupus   20
#3     C.famil   90
#4  O.spatacus   30
#5 O.cuniculus   70
#6  O.spatacus   10
```

```
data <- structure(list(COL1 = c("C.lupus", "C.lupus", "C.famil", "O.cuniculus", 
"O.cuniculus", "O.cuniculus"), COL2 = c(10L, 20L, 90L, 30L, 70L, 
10L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```